# batch script login sqlplus parameters

Tags: batch-file, localhost, sqlplus

I'm having some problem with connecting to database with sqlplus in batchfile.
I'm trying to create a batch-script which prompt for server/service_name, username and password.
It looks something like this:

```
    set /P ORCL=Enter server or service_name:
    set /P UN=Enter DB User:
    set /P PWD=Enter password for DB user:
    sqlplus %UN%/%PWD%@ORCL @.\File_to_run.sql

    ...
```

I'm not using TNS locally, but connecting With machinename, like this:

```
    username/password@machinename:1521/service_name
```

This Works just fine when I starting sqlplus through cmd prompt, but not when I'm running this bat-file. It says that the username or password is wrong and prompting for a username and password...

I think it might be something With the ORCL variable when put into the parameterlist of sqlplus. But I have tried quoting it like this:

```
    ...
    sqlplus %UN%/%PWD%"@ORCL" @.\File_to_run.sql
```

and

```
    sqlplus %UN%/%PWD%@"ORCL" @.\File_to_run.sql
```

But no success...
If I try the same, but instead of @service_name/_string using "AS sysdba" and corresponding username and password, it will work fine.
Does anybody know how to get this right?

BR
FAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use percent sign for the last parameter too. Like:

```
sqlplus "%UN%/%PWD%@%ORCL%" @.\File_to_run.sql
```

I'm not sure why you need the @ sign before .\File_to_run.sql...

Comment: My mistake... I'm using percent signs :-)
like this: sqlplus %UN%/%PWD%@%ORCL% @.\file.sql

The @ before the file to be run is sqlplus specific sign, so it has to be there:-)

Comment: Does the code above solve your issue? Please  notice first parameter is in double-quotes. You need to enter 'machinename:1521/service_name' value for ORCL input.